# Is there a better way to go up in the DOM than this?

Tags: jquery, dom, parent

I was wondering if there is a better / more efficient way to go up the DOM to find a parents sibling and an H1 tag within it.
Here's what I'm using and it works but I bet there's a better way.

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().find('h1').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).closest('h1').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
```

That might not be exactly what you need but .closest() and .parents() are much better to search up the DOM tree than chaining .parent() calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use of  Html Agility Pack (HAP) with help of Nuget packages or directly you can use refer more about

http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Sample codes refer

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples